# Проблема с парсером страницы python

Tags: python, requests, bs4

Пытаюсь парсить названия продуктов на сайте магазина Перекрёсток: https://www.perekrestok.ru/cat/c/211/soki-nektary. Однако список спарсеных результатов пуст. Смотрел Network XHR аякса нету. Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


r = requests.get("https://www.perekrestok.ru/cat/c/211/soki-nektary", headers={"content-type": "text"})
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')
print(html)
el = html.find_all("div", class_="product-card__title")
print(el)
```

Почему результаты не парсятся и как это исправить?

Comment: В запросах вижу POST-запрос, который обращается на `/api/customer/1.4.0.0/catalog/product/grouped-feed`, чтобы забрать `json` с объектами (в данном случае соками) страницы. Попробуйте с ним поработать.

Comment: @Andy Pavlov Только как по этому урэлу работать, если при переходе по нему и при реквести на него появляется ошибка: {"content":null,"error":{"code":"ACCESS_TOKEN_INVALID","message":"Access token invalid."}}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там есть XHR запросы к https://www.perekrestok.ru/api/customer/1.4.0.0/catalog и к https://www.perekrestok.ru/api/customer/1.4.0.0/catalog/product/grouped-feed
но для доступа к ним из веб страницы запросы идут с сессионным ключом который передаётся параметром заголовка Auth: Bearer <код ключа>,

Этот указывается в поле куке session в поле accessToken.

Поэтому нужно:

1. Вначале с правильным User-Agent обратится к веб-странице и получить куку
2. Извлечь токен из session.accessToken
3. Использовать токен для передачи Auth: Bearer <значение assessToken> в headers запроса.

Comment: Спасибо, большое получилось!